# Replace text in file if previous line matches another text

Tags: macos, shell, awk, sed

My file looks like this:

```
FooBarA
foo bar
foo = bar
FooBarB
foo bar
foo = bar
FooBarC
foo bar
foo = bar
...
```

What I would like to do is to write a script that replaces the `bar` in `foo = bar` but only if it belongs to `FooBarB`. So in the example above only the second `bar` out of all `foo = bar` lines should be replaced.

I've played around with `sed` but I just can't get it done right. I would also like to avoid installing any tools that aren't necessarily pre-installed on the system (I'm on Mac OS), since the script will be used by other team members too.

Comment: I suspect you'll be far more likely to get a solution by adding `awk` tag and removing `replace` or `lookbehind`. You might consider `Perl` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it with `sed` (tested using macOS's sed and GNU sed), would be this:

###### replace.sed

```
#!/usr/bin/env sed -Ef

/FooBarB/,/^FooBar/ {
  s/(foo[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*).+/\1new-value/
}
```

Here's what it does:

1. `/FooBarB/,/^FooBar/` matches a range of lines where the first line matches the regex `/FooBarB/` and the last line matches the regex `/^FooBar/` (which is the start of the next "group"). The comma between the two regexes is the syntax for range matching in `sed`.
2. `s/(foo[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*).+/\1new-value/` — [s]ubstitutes (in the matched range of lines) whatever matches the regex `(foo[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*).+` with `\1new-value`, where `\1` references the first capturing group in the search regex. The search regex looks for `foo` followed by optional whitespace, followed by an `=` sign, followed again by whitespace and then whatever else is there, which in your case is the old value.

You could do it all in just one line, but I wanted to show a version that's a bit more digestible (as far as `sed` goes, in any case):

```
sed -E '/FooBarA/,/^FooBar/s/(foo[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*).+/\1new-value/' temp.md
```

Comment: This is basically almost what I need. Is there a way to tell `sed` to only replace the first match of `foo = bar`?. Currently it replaces everything from the actual `foo = bar` that needs to be replaced to the last one in the file

Comment: @ProtocolGuy not sure I understand. Can you edit the sample input in your question? Do you have more than one lines that start with `foo = ` in the `FooBarB` group?

Comment: Ah sry I've messed up. There are actually no new lines in between...

Comment: @ProtocolGuy then all you need to do is adjust the regex for the end of the range; instead of an empty line it should be a line that starts with `FooBar`. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/FooBarB/{:a;n;/^$/b;/foo = bar/!ba;s//foo = baz/}' file
```

Match on the string `FooBarB` and start a loop.

Fetch the next line and study it.

If the line is empty the stanza is done, so break out of the loop.

If the line does not contains the string `foo = bar`, fetch the next line and continue the loop.

Otherwise, substitute the new value for `bar` and finish the loop.

---

Alternative (which may work for macos users?):

```
sed -e '/FooBarB/{:a' -e 'n;/^$/b;/foo = bar/!ba;s//foo = baz/;}' file
```

---

Since the OP changed the input data to the question another solution:

```
sed '/FooBar/h;G;/FooBarB/s/foo = bar/foo = baz/;P;d' file
```

Comment: Nice idea, but **GNU** `sed` would require installation, probably via **homebrew**, on **macos**.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have not used any GNU specific terms in the above but I am aware that the sed macos uses does present some anomalies even to such generic solutions.

Comment: Yeah, `sed` on macOS requires that labels be followed by newlines, so this doesn't work as is. (Also, that the group closing brace is preceded by a semicolon: `;}`)

Comment: @potong macOS is adamant on newlines, it won't work with separate `-e` commands either. One possible solution for `bash` users would be to use a `$''` string and place newlines (`\n`) in the right spots: `sed $'/FooBarB/{:a\n n;/^$/b \n /foo = bar/!ba\n s//foo = baz/; }' temp.md`

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v tgt='FooBarB' -v val='whatever'  '
    NF==1{tag=$0} (NF>1) && (tag==tgt) && sub(/=.*/,"= "){$0=$0 val}
1' file
FooBarA
foo bar
foo = bar
FooBarB
foo bar
foo = whatever
FooBarC
foo bar
foo = bar
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the GNU awk variant:

```
awk -v v="newvalue" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\n";RS=ORS="\n\n"}$1=="FooBarB"{$3="foo = " v}1' file
```

By using the option `-v`, the variable `v` holds the wanted string.

The `BEGIN` statement sets respectively the input, output *field* separator, the input and output *record* separator to one and two carriage return.
That way a record is composed of the block of several lines containing the pattern `Foobar[ABC]`.

The last statement sets the new value by rewriting the third line.

Comment: The only thing that's gawk-specific in that is `RS="\n\n"`. If you changed `RS=ORS="\n\n"` to `RS=""; ORS="\n\n"` then it'd behave the same way in any awk. Having said that, there's no blank lines between data lines in the users sample input (maybe it changed after you answered, idk) so the script won't work.